# ProgressRing does not visible when trying to update UI by running some other process in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, async-await, mahapps.metro

I am working on WPF application. I am using MahApps Metro controls and theme in my application. I want to show a Loading indicator when some other process is running. This process will also update the UI. The problem is loading Indicator does not display.

```
<mah:ProgressRing x:Name="loadingIndicator" Grid.RowSpan="2" 
                          Foreground="{DynamicResource AccentColorBrush}"
                          IsActive="{Binding IsLoading}" />

private async void ExecuteButton_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (DataContext is ExecutionWindowViewModel viewModel)
        {
            if (outputTab.Items.Count > 0)
            {
                outputTab.Items.Clear();
            }
            var selectedDatabases = viewModel.Databases.Where(x => x.IsSelected == true).ToList();
            viewModel.IsLoading = true;
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                this.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                {
                    foreach (var database in selectedDatabases)
                    {
                        TabItem tabItem = new TabItem();
                        tabItem.Header = database.DBShortName;
                        DataGrid sqlOutput = new DataGrid();
                        sqlOutput.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
                        sqlOutput.IsReadOnly = true;
                        var test = viewModel.SQLQueryExecution(database.ConnectionString);
                        sqlOutput.ItemsSource = viewModel.SQLQueryExecution(database.ConnectionString).AsDataView();
                        tabItem.Content = sqlOutput;
                        outputTab.Items.Add(tabItem);
                    }
                }));
            });
            viewModel.IsLoading = false;
        }
    }
```

loading property is like

```
private bool _isLoading = false;
    public bool IsLoading
    {
        get => _isLoading;
        set
        {
            if (_isLoading != value)
            {
                _isLoading = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsLoading));
            }
        }
    }
```

On the button Click event, I want to execute multiple SQL queries, and based on the result I want to create multiple tabs.

**Can anyone help me why ProgressRing is not visible?**

**I have also tried the below code and it is working correctly,**

```
private async void ExecuteButton_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (DataContext is ExecutionWindowViewModel viewModel)
        {
            if (outputTab.Items.Count > 0)
            {
                outputTab.Items.Clear();
            }
            var selectedDatabases = viewModel.Databases.Where(x => x.IsSelected == true).ToList();
            
            viewModel.IsLoading = true;
            await Task.Delay(10000);
            viewModel.IsLoading = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: It looks like your Task returns faster than expected. In other words, reading data from the database is too fast. Additionally you must learn how to use DataTemplates. Creating controls manually must be avoided in order to produce clean code. For example this would make the Dispatcher call obsolete. Another flaw with your code is that the complete Task is executed on the Dispatcher i.e. the UI thread. Creating a task and then post the complete work back to the UI thread is waste of resources and will only cost you performance. Simply remove the Dispatcher.Invoke from your code.

Comment: Another important improvement of your implementation would to execute the database access directly in your view model and not in your view. For this purpose you would attach an ICommand to the Button. The ICommand is implemented in the view model. This will make your code much cleaner and easier to maintain.

Comment: Also from the naming of your view model methods I assume that the view model class directly communicates with the database. You should know that when implementing MVVM properly, your view model wouldn't do that because data persistence is implemented in the model. Your view model class would have to use a model class to get the data. The model class then could read this data from a database or file. or a service like a REST service. This details are usually hidden from the view model. The view model only gets data from an anonymous source. This source is only known to by model.

Answer (score -1):

It is OK to execute the data base access in a different Task as you did. But you should not use the dispatcher invoke method the way you did it. When you use the dispatcher the data base access is done under the UI thread and it blocks the UI update.
While the task is running , you can use the dispatcher invoke for the update of UI related properties only.
By doing so you will not block the UI with lengthy SQL calls and still be able to update the UI.
The IsLoading property is actually set to false immediately!
The Sequence is as following: The task is starting, it sends to the dispatcher an action to be execute and the task is terminating and setting the IsLoading to false. After that the SQL part is executed under the UI thread with the action you set before.

I include a working code that is slightly modified.

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ProgressBar Grid.Row="0" IsIndeterminate="{Binding IsLoading}" />
        <TabControl Grid.Row="1" Name="outputTab"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="2" Click="Button_Click" Width="100">Load</Button>
    </Grid>


public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = new ExecutionWindowViewModel();
        }
        private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (DataContext is ExecutionWindowViewModel viewModel)
            {
                if (outputTab.Items.Count > 0)
                {
                    outputTab.Items.Clear();
                }
                var selectedDatabases = viewModel.Databases;
                viewModel.IsLoading = true;
                await Task.Run(() =>
                {
                        foreach (var database in selectedDatabases)
                        {
                            
                            viewModel.SQLQueryExecution();
                            
                            this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => {
                                DataGrid sqlOutput = new DataGrid();
                                sqlOutput.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
                                sqlOutput.IsReadOnly = true;
                                TabItem tabItem = new TabItem();
                                tabItem.Header = database.ToString();
                                tabItem.Content = sqlOutput;
                                outputTab.Items.Add(tabItem); }));

                        }
                        this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => { viewModel.IsLoading = false; }));
                    
                });
                
            }
        }
    }




public class ExecutionWindowViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public ExecutionWindowViewModel()
        {
            Databases = new List<string>();
            Databases.Add("DB1");
            Databases.Add("DB2");
            Databases.Add("DB3");
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void NotifyPropertyChanged( String propertyName )
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
        bool _isLoading;
        public bool IsLoading
        {
            get { return _isLoading; }
            set {
                    _isLoading = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(IsLoading));
                }
        }
        public List<string> Databases { get; set; }

        public  void  SQLQueryExecution()
        {
            Thread.Sleep(3000);
        }

    }
```

As of the comments I am adding another flavor for the code behind. But also the first one I posted is working and is legitimate. I also agree that this is not the best practice regarding the VM but this is not the issue here.

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (DataContext is ExecutionWindowViewModel viewModel)
            {
                if (outputTab.Items.Count > 0)
                {
                    outputTab.Items.Clear();
                }
                var selectedDatabases = viewModel.Databases;
                viewModel.IsLoading = true;
                await Task.Run(() =>
                {
                        foreach (var database in selectedDatabases)
                        {
                            
                            viewModel.SQLQueryExecution();
                                this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => {
                                    DataGrid sqlOutput = new DataGrid();
                                sqlOutput.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
                                sqlOutput.IsReadOnly = true;
                                TabItem tabItem = new TabItem();
                                tabItem.Header = database.ToString();
                                tabItem.Content = sqlOutput;
                                outputTab.Items.Add(tabItem); });
                        }
                });
                viewModel.IsLoading = false;
               

            }
        }
```

Comment: You should not do that either. Just put `viewModel.IsLoading = false;` outside the `Task.Run`. it's functionally close and easier to decouple from UI.

Comment: Your explanation is not correct. Because of the `await` the execution is "synchronous". Also Dispatcher.Invoke is synchronous. In the given scenario there is no reason why the line `viewModel.IsLoading = false;` is executed prematurely. The only reasonable reason is that the Task is returning faster than expected. There is also no need to execute the property assignment on the Dispatcher. PropertyChanged is automatically marshaled to the UI thread by the binding engine.

Comment: For the sake of completeness, the logic of setting IsLoading and the database handling should be completely hidden from the view. The view should not actively participate in this kind of logic. The correct way would be to move this logic completely to the View Model and trigger it by preferably using an ICommand. The View Model would then manage the IsLoading state and generate a data source for the View. The View would define DataTemplates to generate controls dynamically and populate them with data using data bindings that use the View Model as binding source.